How do I centre Kivymd's MDDialog title?
I'm trying to centre this MDDialog's title so it's in the middle. Apparently, there's no inbuilt method for doing that. Anyone know a way or a hack around it?
self.dialog = MDDialog(
                type = "custom",
                title = "Edit Profile Info",
                radius = [35, ] * 4,
                # change auto_dismiss back to True
                auto_dismiss = False,
                content_cls = content,
            )

        self.dialog.open()



If you use KivyMD version 2.0.1, you can use MDDialogHeadlineText to center the title, like this:
    self.dialog = MDDialog(
        MDDialogIcon(
            icon="refresh",
        ),
        MDDialogHeadlineText(
            text="Edit Profile Info",
        ),
        content,

